# string to long, not giving me the correct answer

Tags: c, linux, string, long-integer

I am trying to convert number stored in the c string to long int. But I am not getting the expected output:

```
char str[] = "987654321012345";
long int num ;
num = 0;
//num = atol(str);
num = strtol(str, (char **) NULL, 10);
printf("%ld", num);
```

Output : `821493369`

gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
Can you please advise what am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `long` is big enough for your number? Are you on a 64-bit system? Perhaps you should be using `long long`, `strtoll` and `"%lld"`?

Comment: Yes I am on 64 bit arch. And I already tried using strtoll and result is same.

Comment: What is the issue? Seems [fine](https://ideone.com/MpVv5z) to me with `long long`

Comment: I am getting the output 821493369 instead of 987654321012345 using gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)

Comment: What does `sizeof(long)` and `sizeof(long long)` report? Does either or both say `8`? Then you should not have a problem. And you remembered to change your data-type to `long long`? And change the `printf` format to `"%lld"`?

Comment: are you sure that your compiler is generating the 64bit code?

Comment: @PeterJ how to make sure that compiler generates 64bit code? $ arch
x86_64

Comment: check the size of the `int` `long` and `long long`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   When asking a question about a runtime problem, (as this question is) post code that cleanly compiles, is short, and still exhibits the the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to using `long long`, you can use *exact width* types from `stdint.h`. For instance, to guarantee and 64-bit *signed* number you can use the `int64_t` type. Regardless what you do, **do not cast** `NULL` to `char **` and **always** validate your conversions. E.g.,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (void) {

    char str[] = "987654321012345";
    long num = 0;
    errno = 0;

    num = strtol (str, NULL, 10);
    if (errno) {    /* validate strtol conversion */
        perror ("strtol conversion failed.");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("%ld\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtoltst
987654321012345
```

There are additional error checks you can do on the conversion, but at minimum, make sure `errno` is not set following your call to `strtol` or `strtoll`.

If you would like to use the *guaranteed width types*, then you can make the following changes:

```
...
#include <stdint.h>
...
    int64_t num = 0;
    ...
    num = strtoll (str, NULL, 10);
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Glad it helped. There is a lot to learn with C. Take your time and enjoy the process `:)`

Comment: Thank you David C. Rankin :)

Comment: Since the second pointer is `NULL` (`**endptr`) in the full declaration, all you can do is check `errno` and the ERANGE values. If there were a second pointer, then we could check for 'no-digits' and `0`, but without it, you only have `errno`.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but `"In both cases, errno is set to ERANGE"` -- so checking `errno` is appropriate. That is why I expressly noted that this check was an `"at minimum"` check. Pulling in `limits.h` and checking the over/underflow values would be the complete check here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude from `strtol` manpage: *"Since  strtol() can legitimately return 0, LONG_MAX, or LONG_MIN (LLONG_MAX or LLONG_MIN for strtoll()) on both success and failure, **the calling program should set errno to 0** before the call,  **and then** determine if an error occurred by **check**ing whether **errno has a nonzero value** after the call."* -- Seems David C. Rankin is doing the right thing here.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Heh, missed that the code in the answer *do* clear `errno` before. And to David, sorry for misreading the code.

Comment: The point being here was a minimum check to see if the conversion succeeded, if `errno` is not set, no error occurred. Yes the check of any return of `LLONG_MAX` or `LLONG_MIN` is appropriate, but completely unnecessary unless alternative action will be taken for one or the other. Here we are bailing on a failed conversion -- that's it. I don't disagree with the checks, but I do disagree with any suggestion the `errno` check is wrong.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin - yep, even a blind squirrel finds a nut every now and then, but good to know both of you will school me quick if I stray outside the line `:)`

Comment: The `int64_t` idea  detracts from the answer. As C lacks a `strtoint64()` incorporating that type with `strtoll()/strtol()` is problematic.

Answer (score 3):

I could reproduce and fix.

Code reproducing the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>   

int main()
{
    char str[] = "987654321012345";
    long int num ;
    char *ix;
    num = 0;
    //num = atol(str);
    num = strtol(str, &ix, 10);
    printf("%ld\n", num);
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(long));
    return 0;
}
```

Gives as expected:

```
821493369
8
```

After a compilation warning

> warning: implicit declaration of strtoll

Reason: as `strtoll` is undeclared, it is assumed to return an `int`, so the long value is first truncate to an int and than promoted back to a long.

Fix: just uncomment the `#include <stdlib.h>` line...

Conclusion: warnings are not meant to be ignored!

Comment: Thanks @Serge Ballesta for reproducing the problem and giving the reason why the output was coming the way it was coming, Upvoted.

Comment: @CppLearner: that's the reason why a question should include a [mcve] :-)

Comment: , my bad, I apologize for the same. I thought I gave the total information. Thanks a lot for your time for investigating this. Sincerely.

Comment: This answer well addresses OP's results.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `long long` as datatype for your number.

```
char str[] = "987654321012345";
long long num = strtoll(str, (char **)NULL, 10);
printf("%lld", num);
```

Comment: Already tried and I am getting the same output using strtoll.

Comment: @CppLearner did you use `strtoll` and `lld` format flag when printing with `printf`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [C data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types):

> - Long signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−2,147,483,647, +2,147,483,647] range; thus, it is at least 32 bits in size.
> - Long unsigned integer type. Capable of containing at least the [0, 4,294,967,295] range;

Is not enough, so you need a `long long` or `unsigned long long` and use `%lli` or `%llu`

Comment: Even that is not working :( char str[] = "987654321012345";
unsigned long long int num ;
num = 0;
//num = atol(str);
num = strtoll(str, (char **) NULL, 10);
printf("%llu", num);

Comment: Had OP code used a 32-bit `long`, then output would have been 2147483648, not 821493369.  The issue is not due to `long` size.

Comment: @chux, For me, it's not take the max value but the binary value fit in the type size, ex:  
On my computer sizeof(long) = 8, ```987654321012345``` -> ```11100000100100010000110000111101101111111001111001```  
sizeof(int) = 4, ```111000001001000100 [00110000111101101111111001111001]``` -> ```821493369```

Comment: 1 By using the max value, rather than size, code takes into account padding, a rare aspect of some implementations.  2 This answer does address a concern of conversions, yet on OP's machine, the size of `long` was 8 bytes and `strtol(987654321012345, ...)` is not a range issue for OP.

Answer (score 0):

"987654321012345" is too large.

- Strol is outputing long type variable.
- Long value is –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

try

```
char str[] = "987654321012345";
char *pEnd;
long long num;
num = 0;
num = strtoull(str,&pEnd, 10);
printf("%lld", num);
return 0;
```

- long long instead of long
- strtoull instead of strtol
- %lld instead of %ld

Comment: "987654321012345" is _not_ too large with OP's 64-bit `long`.  "Long value is –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647." is the minimum range in C.  `long` may be wider, as in OP's case.  OP's code and this are both missing a `strto*()` prototype and so share the same problem.  Unclear why this answer suggest `strtoull()` and not `strtoll()`.